# expects at least X parameters - Warnings, Notices

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, mysqli

Working on a login for admins on my webpage. I am following a tutorial that is kind of old, and I am trying to update it for MYSQLI. On his video, everything works perfect.. For me however..

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    if(empty($username) or empty($password)) {

        echo "<p class='warn'>Oops!</p>";

    } else { 

        $checklogin = mysqli_query(" SELECT id FROM admins WHERE username='$username' AND password='password' ");

        if(mysqli_num_rows($checklogin) == 1){

            echo "You can log in.";

        } else {

            echo "Oops";

        }
    }
}
```

and

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/WEBSITES/Site1/admin/login.php on line 29

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/WEBSITES/Site1/admin/login.php on line 31
```

Comment: I would recommed to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). IMO it's safier and easier to use than MySQLi.

Comment: Are you sure that the error isn't caused by the missing $ in your mysqli_query? The $ is missing in the part `[..]AND password='$password'");`

Comment: Don't use MD5 with passwords. PHP5 has new functions for handling password hashes.

Comment: @Kommodore still getting the error

Comment: @user3725053 As far as I know, PDO  and MySQLi offer exactly the same features in terms of security. Which is easier is a matter of taste, but the procedural functions in MySQLi are more similar to the old mysql_* functions used in old tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `mysqli_query()` requires the first parameter to be your connection to the database, which would have been returned during `mysqli_connect()`.  That is your first warning.

Since you didn't provide a connection to `mysqli_query()` the return value of `$checkLogin` equals `null`, this is where your second warning comes in.  `mysqli_num_rows()` expects a result set from a successful query.

Here is your fix:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "yourDB");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT some, fields FROM YourTable WHERE something = 'this'");
```

Comment: Already had a connection established, but did not put that `$connection` in the `mysqli_query`. It works now. Thanks. Will accept when I can.

Comment: @Razzey Glad it is working.  Please note that many of the procedural versions of the MySQLi library functions require a connection, a result, etc.  Make sure you consult the manual on these functions to find out any parameters you may need.

Comment: Wil do, thank you! Still learning all of this PHP and databases stuff. Have a good day/evening/night!

Comment: @Razzey You are welcome.  I would also suggest you look at the other comments and answer relating to MD5 and password hashing.  I would also suggest that you utilize prepared statements to help prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 3):

Errors about incorrect parameters can often be solved by looking up the manual for the function in question.

In this case, go to http://php.net/mysqli_query and you will see this function summary:

> mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )

So the two parameters expected are the `mysqli` object representing the connection to the database (which you will get when you first connect), and then the string of SQL to run (which you are currently passing).

The second error is a consequence of the first: because you are not checking for errors, `$checklogin` doesn't represent a successful query result.

---

Incidentally, there are a few other problems you might want to look at here, if the tutorial doesn't go on to explain them:

- md5 is not a secure method for hashing passwords. Take a look at [this for a more secure solution](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.password.php), or at least use a more up to date hash function.
- you are checking `empty($password)`, but have already applied a hashing function, which will never return an empty string
- you are wide open to SQL injection; see [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)